# How does one use SBCL's SB-SPROF allocation profiling?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime, sbcl

**Update: Upgrading to SBCL 1.0.24 fixed my problem.  (Though I also needed to upgrade SLIME to the 11-23-2008 revision.  The stable 2006-04-20 revision, as well as the head of CVS don't seem to work with SBCL 1.0.24.)**

The [documentation](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/Statistical-Profiler.html) for the SBCL statistical profiler indicates that you can profile memory allocation in addition to CPU usage.  However, for the life of me, I have not been able to get it to profile more than a trivial Lisp form.  Here's an example of what happens:

```
CL-USER> (require :sb-sprof)
("SB-SPROF")
CL-USER> (defun ! (n)
           (if (= n 1)
               1
               (* n (! (- n 1)))))
!
CL-USER> (sb-sprof:with-profiling (:mode :alloc :loop nil :show-progress t :max-samples 100 :report :flat)
           (dotimes (n 100)
             (print n)
             (! 10)))
===> 0 of 100 samples taken.

0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
Profiler sample vector full (12 traces / 1000 samples), doubling the size
Profiler sample vector full (17 traces / 2000 samples), doubling the size
Profiler sample vector full (25 traces / 4000 samples), doubling the size
Profiler sample vector full (36 traces / 8000 samples), doubling the size
Profiler sample vector full (52 traces / 16000 samples), doubling the size
Profiler sample vector full (74 traces / 32000 samples), doubling the size
```

At this point, it usually hangs.

Has anyone had success with this?

Comment: Hanging doesn't sound good, so you should at least specify what version you are using and on what platform. Reporting that on the sbcl-devel mailing list would probably be a good idea, too.

Comment: Does it make the Swank thread hang also?

Comment: I'm running SBCL x86 1.0.17 on OS X 10.5.6.

Comment: jrockway, yes, I couldn't even interrupt it.  In general I had to kill the sbcl process.  However, upgrading to 1.0.24 has fixed things.  Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Works for me (i.e. no hanging) except that your example conses very little and takes 1ms to run so you probably want to take more samples and pass :LOOP T instead.